# J-query on Select Option the input field is not hidden

Tags: jquery, laravel

I created two form on one route and then one fiorm display is none and then put a button on form1 and click the button it is moved to form2 and then on this form the selected option is placed and then selected some option i want to hide some input on select the option but selected option is not working.

```
$(function () {
        $('#purpose_type_id').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var selected_option = $('#purpose_type_id').val();
            console.log(selected_option);
            if (selected_option == "3" | selected_option == "4") {
                $("#plot_number_div").hide();
                $("#property_address_div").hide();
            } else {
                $("#plot_number_div").show();
                $("#property_address_div").show();
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Please add full code fiddle. with HTML

Comment: thanks i solve my problem